# re.match pattern matching with ^,$

Tags: python, regex

In the code below:

```
    >>> pattern = re.compile(r'^<HTML>')
    >>> pattern.match("<HTML>")
    <_sre.SRE_Match at 0x1043bc8b8>
    >>> pattern.match("⇢ ⇢ <HTML>", 2) # ⇢ stands for whitespace character.
    None
```

When we are using ^ metacharacter and matching pattern then any whitespace character at the beginning as given below doesn't give a match even if the

> 'pos' argument is equal to 2, and the reason being given was that the
>   metacharacter ^ couldn't be matched in such cases( < is at position 2, and it cannot be matched with ^).

```
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'<HTML>$')
>>> pattern.match("<HTML>⇢", 0,6) # ⇢ stands for whitespace character.
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x1007033d8>
>>> pattern.match("<HTML>⇢"[:6])
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x100703370>
```

But, when we are using $ at the end of regular expression and giving the 'end' argument there is a match? Why the difference?

Comment: In general you should avoid using regex to parse HTML content.  Use an HTML parser instead.

Comment: Just as Tim stated, you should avoid regex for parsing html content. Maybe try BeautifulSoup.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: This is just a general question.

Comment: `"⇢ ⇢ <HTML>", 2) # ⇢ stands for whitespace character.`: the arrows are a little misleading. You have whitespaces and arrows which stands for whitespaces in this line. So is it 4 x whitespace or only 2 times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to dig a little into the docs, but the answer lies there. You will find the following information in the docs for [`pattern.search`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Pattern.search), the same description applies to [`pattern.match`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Pattern.match) as well.

> The optional second parameter pos gives an index in the string where
>   the search is to start; it defaults to 0. This is not completely
>   equivalent to slicing the string; **the `'^'` pattern character matches at
>   the real beginning of the string** and at positions just after a
>   newline, **but not necessarily at the index where the search is to
>   start.**

So, this means the SOL anchor `^` will match from the true beginning of the string (and not from the position dictated by `pos`. OTOH,

> The optional parameter endpos limits how far the string will be
>   searched; it will be as if the string is endpos characters long, **so
>   only the characters from `pos` to `endpos - 1` will be searched for a
>   match.**

Emphasis mine. Meaning that a pattern with the EOL anchor `^` will actually match upto `endpos` only (unlike `pos`).

Comment: Well, to achieve what OP wants, in this case, just remove the anchor from the regex. `match` already makes sure the match starts from `pos` in this case.